# validation rule only one user profile can edit status when status is Approved

Tags: formula, validation-rule

I have Validation Rule

```
AND
(
$Profile.Name <> "System Administrator",
TEXT(Approval_Status__c) = "Approved"
)
```

I need that only System Administrator can edit Receipt when Approval Status is Approved

But also I need that all users can change Approval Status to Approved.
How I need to change my Validation Rule?

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! I assume that "Receipt" is the object on which the above Validation Rules is placed?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not feasible,even if we try to implement it, it will be chaotic,

1. From what I understand you want system admin to be able to change it (no validation rule needed)
2. You don't want other profiles to edit - why don't you make the fields other than approval status read only for all other profiles

Comment: don't use validation rule just make fields read only for all other profiles(go to the profile and set permission )